# How to refer to something that is beyond postmodern?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Here are a few common amalgamations that use 'post' to mark a new reference point:

> modern art -> postmodern art

> modern portfolio theory -> postmodern
> portfolio theory

This is all very intuitive. But suppose that we have a need to add another reference point to show that something is more recent than "post." I initially considered "post postmodern art," but the repetition of words comes off as slightly brute force. I'm hoping there is a more elegant solution for this.

Comment: Are you asking specifically about art? Consider "contemporary art", or some other more specific art movement. If not, different disciplines will have different terminologies, and different cut-offs, but you could also use a date, e.g. post-1980 or post-2000. Really, unless you are talking about something that arose explicitly as a reaction to postmodernism and doesn't have any other identifying feature, you should consider a more descriptive term.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, you could use **cutting-edge** to describe such things:

> The latest or most advanced stage in the development of something.

*researchers at the cutting edge of molecular biology*

*Stem cell experimentation, for example, is a complex, multifaceted enterprise that advances at the cutting edge of scientific understanding.*

[Lexico]